# I want to see a window created by an external process called in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I don't think the program I want to use is famous among people not related to seismology. But what I want to use is a utility software of seismograms.
anyway it is an interactive software basically we use in shell.

(SAC means seismic analysis code)

> SAC> read "a file name"
>
> SAC> plot

then it will create a window showing a waveform.

I want to do this in Java by ProcessBuilder and Process.
I do not care actually what class I use, its just I know only them to do such a thing.

I created a class which gives a Process for the SAC.
Both standard output and error is read by another thread, respectively,
as I googled it and it told that one possible reason of matters in Process is
related to those. (Even though SAC does not return output error so much...)

After I started those threads.start(), I write "read filename" and "plot"
to standard input , but nothing happens. A window sometime show up when a program exits.

Here is my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
 try(Sac sac = Sac.createProcess()){ 
   // Class Sac governs a Process for SAC
    sac.inputCMD("r abc.R"); 
   // inputCMD is writing in standard input and flush immediately
    sac.inputCMD("plot");
    
      for (;;) // this is just for time to see what is going on
        ;
     }
}
```

I will say again but
When I kill a Java run, a window sometime pop and disappears very soon.

I think this is a related to thread issues.
because when I call SAC#inputCMD("plot") from another thread, then a window pops instantly everytime.

Is it a problem that I create SAC in main?

---- Added ----
I mentioned about the order from other threads. but it often does not work as well...

Here is a Class Sac and ExternalProcess

```
public class Sac extends ExternalProcess implements Closeable {

 Sac(Process process) {
     super(process);
     standardInput = new PrintWriter(super.standardInput);
 }

  public static Sac createProcess() throws IOException {
      ProcessBuilder builder = null;
      if (checkEnvironment())
          builder = new ProcessBuilder("sac");
      else
          throw new RuntimeException("No sac in PATH or No SACAUX is set.");

      return new Sac(builder.start());
  }

/**
 * Make an order to Sac
 * 
 * @param line
 *            command line for SAC
 */
  public void inputCMD(String line) {
    standardInput.println(line);
    standardInput.flush();
}

  @Override
  public void close() {
    try {
        standardInput.println("q");
        standardInput.flush();
        standardInput.close();
        process.waitFor();
        standardOutput.join();
        standardError.join();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

  private static boolean checkEnvironment() {
    // String sachome = System.getenv("SACHOME");
    boolean sacExistence = System.getenv("PATH").contains("/sac/bin");
    String sacaux = System.getenv("SACAUX");
    return sacExistence && sacaux != null;
  }

/**
 * Input for Sac
 */
  private PrintWriter standardInput;
}
```

Here is ExternalProcess.

```
public class ExternalProcess {
 /**
  * {@link Stream} for standard output
  */
  protected InputStreamThread standardOutput;

 /**
  * {@link Process} for Sac
  */
  protected Process process;

 /**
  * {@link Stream} for standard error
  */
  protected InputStreamThread standardError;

 /**
  * connected to standard input
  */
  protected OutputStream standardInput;

  ExternalProcess(Process process) {
      this.process = process;
      standardOutput = new InputStreamThread(process.getInputStream());
      standardError = new InputStreamThread(process.getErrorStream());
      standardError.start();
      standardOutput.start();
      standardInput = process.getOutputStream();

  }

  public static ExternalProcess launch(String... command) throws IOException {
     ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
     return new ExternalProcess(builder.start());

 }

 /**
  * @return {@link OutputStream} connected to a standard input to the
  *         process
  */
 public OutputStream getStandardInput() {
    return standardInput;
 }

 /**
  * @return {@link InputStreamThread} connected to a standard output to the
  *         process
  */
  public InputStreamThread getStandardOutput() {
     return standardOutput;
  }

 /**
  * @return {@link InputStreamThread} connected to a standard error to the
  *         process
  */
  public InputStreamThread getStandardError() {
    return standardError;
  }

public static ExternalProcess launch(List<String> command) throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    return new ExternalProcess(builder.start());

}

  public int waitFor() {
     try {
         int process = this.process.waitFor();
         standardError.join();
         standardOutput.join();
         return process;
     } catch (Exception e) {
         throw new RuntimeException();
     }

  }

}
```

and finally InputStreamThread

```
public class InputStreamThread extends Thread {

/**
 * if the stream is closed
 */
  private boolean closed;

 /**
  * Wait until the inputstream is closed and return String[]
  * @return {@link String}[] from input stream
  */
  public String[] waitAndGetString(){
    try {
        while(!closed)
            Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
 }

 @Override
 public void run() {
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)) {
        for (;;) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            if (line == null)
                break;
            list.add(line);
            //System.out.println(line+" "+list.size());
        }
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally{
        closed = true;
    }
 }



 /**
 * List of String from the stream 
 * 文字列の取得
 * @return {@link List} of {@link String} from the {@link InputStream}
  */
 public List<String> getStringList() {
    return list;
 }

 private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();



 private InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;


 public InputStreamThread(InputStream is) {
    inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(is);
 }


}
```

Comment: You should post the code for class Sac as well.

Comment: Why is the standardInput initialized with the process standard output?

standardInput = process.getOutputStream();

Comment: This is just for my naming sense.  (OutputStream standardInput) is an OutputStream connected to standard input

Comment: Whole other question that might change my answer ( meaning you'd have to parse the outputstream ---  )  How long does it take to "read" the input file in SAC, and will SAC not accept input until it's done ( i.e. till it's echoed the prompt again? )

Comment: Thank you for your comment and answer. I am still reading your answer, but i reply first,
"read hoge" of SAC is quite instant.

Comment: "quite instant" is not the same as instant.  It can be a hick up in reading the input, if only for a millisecond, that prevents SAC from reading input correctly.  I'll edit my post for example.

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguous expression, but it looks a window will never show up unless inputCMD from another thread during for loop in main method.  If I kill a running job (I am testing in eclipse), a window pops and disappears.  Similar situation can be seen in an attempt of file output by the SAC.  During the for loop, the SAC does not a file output, but it does when another process inputCMD after sac writing command. or kill the running Java process. If main process has no for loop, the SAC never fails to output. but never write until main finishes

Answer (score 0):

So, a question and an answer.  Question: do you care about what's coming out of standard out/standard err.  If you don't, I'd recommend just starting them piped, which leads me to Answer:

Your ExternalProcess class gets way simpler at that point ( no need to mess around with Input reading echoing threads etc. )

Also, other things you talk about seem to indicate that multiple threads may have access to an instance of ExternalProcess -- that means you should flag your "input" methods as synchronized as well.

I end up with this:

```
package so;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class ExternalProcess {

    private final Process process;
    private final PrintWriter commandWriter;

    public ExternalProcess(String... command) throws IOException {

        process = new ProcessBuilder(command)
                .redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)
                .redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)
                .redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)
                .start();

        commandWriter = new PrintWriter(process.getOutputStream());

    }

    public synchronized ExternalProcess inputCMD(char... chars) {

        if (chars != null && chars.length > 0) {
            commandWriter.write(chars);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public synchronized ExternalProcess inputCMD(String line) {

        commandWriter.println(line);
        commandWriter.flush();
        return this;
    }

    public void waitFor() throws InterruptedException {

        process.waitFor();
    }

    public void stop() {

        process.destroy();
    }

}
```

Then I write a little test to push stuff through my regular shell, including doing some meaningless editing with VI.

```
package so;

import java.io.IOException;

public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        ExternalProcess externalProcess = new ExternalProcess("/bin/bash");
        externalProcess.inputCMD("ls -lah");
        externalProcess.inputCMD("rm /tmp/foo");
        externalProcess.inputCMD("vi /tmp/foo");
        externalProcess.inputCMD("i hello world.");
        externalProcess.inputCMD((char) 0x1B);
        externalProcess.inputCMD(":wq!");

    }

}
```

Seems to work fine.

If you're having issues getting "sac" to respond -- it probably has to do with the sac expecting things off /dev/tty in some odd way.

Note that some of this inevitably platform specific -- If you're differently abled and not in a unixy world, I leave translating this into your universe an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you again. I tried your Class "ExternalProcess". 
However, the problem that a window does not show up instantly is not solved...  
I lauch sac by  
main(String[] args){
 ExternalProcess sac = new ExternalProcess("SACPATH");
sac.inputCMD("r foo");
sac.inputCMD("p");
for(;;);
}

I realized if I put 
for(;;)
sac.inputCMD("");
then a window shows up.

As you says, it might be related to ( If you're having issues getting "sac" to respond -- it probably has to do with the sac expecting things off /dev/tty in some odd way.)